# pdflatex freeze using dgroup+elsarticle combination

Tags: elsarticle

pdflatex freezes when I use `\begin{dgroup} \begin{dmath}` ... `\end{dmath} \end{dgroup}` combination for `\documentclass{elsarticle}`. But if I change the class document for `\documentclass{article}` the compilation is ok. Anyone have any idea what's going on? My equations is very long and `multline` or `eqnarray` make a ugly work, but work...

Thanks,

Otton

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: impossible to say without an example really: try to remove everything from a copy of your document until you get the smallest example that hangs...